# Converting username, to userID for entry into a comments box

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
   include("connection.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 
     $row['userID'] = $myuserid;


      $sql = "SELECT * FROM u803621131_login.users WHERE  username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         session_start("myuserid");


$_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['login_id'] = $myuserid;


         header("location: welcome.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Login Page</title>

      <style type = "text/css">
         body {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
         }

         label {
            font-weight:bold;
            width:100px;
            font-size:14px;
         }

         .box {
            border:#666666 solid 1px;
         }
      </style>

   </head>

   <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">

      <div align = "center">
         <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
            <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>

            <div style = "margin:30px">

               <form action = "" method = "post">
                  <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
                  <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
               </form>

               <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div>

            </div>

         </div>

      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Login.php - The login page with all the changed parts, the actual login works as it should. although it is hard to tell if there are any other issues

```
<?php session_start();
include'../../connection.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".../../../../style.css">
    <title>Home</title>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<?php include('../../main/main.php');?>
</head>
  <body>



<div class=containermain>
  <h1>I5-6600k.php</h1>
<form action="ratepost.php" method="post">

<label for="rating">rating:</label>
<select name="rating" id="rating" value="rating" >
<option>
    <option value="1">1 </option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3 </option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



  <h2>graphics card write up................</h2>
  <?php echo "Hello " . $_SESSION['user']; ?>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>

<!---------------------------------------COMMENT BOX---------------------------------------------------->

<div class="comments" align="center">
<form action="" method="post" >
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment">
Please type a comment if you are logged in....


</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['login_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['login_id'])) {
 $id = $_SESSION['login_id'];
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO comment (userID, comment, dCpuID) VALUES ('$id', '$comment', '1')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert)){


      header("Location: i5-6600k");
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sqlinsert. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}

    // close connection










$sql  = "SELECT `users`.`username`, `comment`.`comment`, `comment`.`timestamp`\n"

    . "FROM `users`\n"

    . "LEFT JOIN `comment` ON `users`.`userID` = `comment`.`userID` \n"

    . "where dCpuID = 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>Username</th><th>Comment</th><th>Timestamp</th>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["comment"]."</td><td>"  . $row["timestamp"]. "</td>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}


?>  
</div>
<?php include('../../assets/footer.php');?>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.computercomparison.tk/#home" data-numposts="5"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Have included entirety of 2nd page, incase there may be clashes with other parts of the code in the site that may be pointed out.

Also you will find lots of code in strange places, only testing bits at the mo.

```
<?php
   include('connection.php');

   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select username, from users where username = '$user_check' ");


   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['username'];


   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:login.php");


   }
?>
```

Have this session.php file, didn't think it was too relevant but changing it around did affect logging in and stuff, it is in good condition here, wonder if there is anything i need to change here too? it is linked to the welcome.php

Comment: Please include the table structure for `users` and `comment`.

Comment: You have foreign key in your comment to userID? Are you sure about that or you just added it accidentally?

Comment: Try selecting the `userID` from the `users` table using the `username` -> `INSERT INTO comment (userID, comment, dCpuID) SELECT \`userID\`, '$comment', '1' FROM users WHERE username = '$username'`

Comment: Yes i have a FK link, will give that query a go.

Comment: You don't need `isset` and `!empty`. The `!emtpy` woill suffice. You should parameterize this query. You also should store the userid in the session, not the name. `dan` is not unique so you won't be able to distinguish one from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the error message you connected a column for the comment authors ID to one in your account table using a foreign key.

As shown in your picture they're both INT. But you are trying to insert a VARCHAR (the username) into this column instead.

My approach would be to get the user's ID by a sql query or even better save the users ID to the session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $usernameFromFormOrWhatever;
$_SESSION['login_id'] = $usersID;
```

So you can fill your userID column with it:

```
$id = $_SESSION['login_id'];
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO comment (userID, comment, dCpuID) VALUES ('$id', '$comment', '1')";
```

Additionally the entered ID in your comments table must also appear in a row of your accounts table as ID of a user. Otherwise you will get an error message like you do now.

Comment: Data types are all set correctly. Have tried replacing my session start with session.php which may hopefully so something, but somewhere down the line, i managed to majorly spam the comment box, cant quite rememeb what i did for that to happen

Comment: @danw20 Just updated my answer. You should save the user's id on login to the session to make use of it later.

Comment: Would it be best to input the first bit into the login.php or session.php file?

Comment: though looking back at it, i think the session.php may well be an old file

Comment: I don't know you're code, but you must insert the first piece of code where your user gets logged in. Note that `session_start();` must be called before.

Comment: Having a few issues inserting the userID into the login script, have entered the little bit of code into the script, but trying to work out the best query to get that info form the DB

Comment: $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 
      


      $sql = "SELECT * FROM u803621131_login.users WHERE  username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];
      
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      
  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count == 1) {
         session_register("myusername");

Comment: the first bit obvs, are getting the info from the login form, and i can' take the userid from the form obviously, and not quite sure how to add to that current query

Comment: `session_register`is deprecated since PHP 5.3. You should use `session_start();` instead. You are already reading the whole row of the table, so you can also make use of the id (column). Just save `$row['nameOfIDColumn']` to a variable, e.g. `$myuserid`,replace session_register with start and than `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername; $_SESSION['login_id'] = $myuserid;`

Comment: Changes have now all been made, however there isn't anything being inserted. Not too sure what is up, will update all the pages above

Comment: Delete  `$row['userID'] = $myuserid;` and change `session_start("myuserid");


$_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['login_id'] = $myuserid;` to `session_start();


$_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['login_id'] = $row['userID'];`

Comment: Ok did that, now when logged in im not able to display the page with the comment box, chrome says too many redirects, also tried on anothre browser same. Appreciate what has been sorted so far

Comment: When logged out the page can be displayed though

Comment: Ok it is now attempting to enter the userID which is great, stuck a close connection right at the top of the php, so it obviously isn't displaying anything and says failing to enter(because of close connection), so your code has definately solved that part thanks